# Principled Volume VS. Volume Scatter VS. Volume Absorption - Key Differences, how they affect the scene and when to use them?

Tags: node-editor, lighting, volumetrics, shader-nodes, filmic-blender

So recently I've been experimenting with an underwater scene in blender and came across a few options for creating the volumetric. I usually go around applying one of the three shaders and see which one works best without understanding its (node) fundamentals. This kept me up all day thinking about what the function would be of the three nodes.
It'd be great if someone could weigh in on this.

best,
AJ

Answer (score 3):

I would say that:

- **Volume Absorption** absorbs lights, you can use it to add thickness to fluids or glass:

[image]

- **Volume Scatter** scatters lights, you can use it to create fog (here I put a spot in a cube that has a *Volume Scatter* in order to create the "god ray" effect), or, if it's lighter, it helps to create depth in a scene:

[image]

- **Principled Volume** is a *Volume Scatter* with more options, like for example *Emission*, it's also used for *Smoke* simulations:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the simple clarification @moonboots.

Comment: you're welcome, maybe someone will give more detailed and technical answer  ;)

Comment: Nah dude, this is the most detailed yet simple the answer can be!

Comment: Principled Volume is to Volume Scatter and Volume Absorption, what Principled BSDF is to Diffusion Shader and Glossy Shader. Principled Nodes are relatively new, complex nodes that take care of multiple things for realistic effects. Whereas Volume Scatter and Volume Absorption are very primitive (not necessarily in a bad sense), where each takes care of a single thing, and usually for a realistic effect you want to mix both - because if you have particles that absorb light, the usually (almost always) also reflect some light back, scattering it.